# how to export underlying data in Power BI report for live connection

Tags: powerbi

I am encountering a problem with all visuals on all Power BI (PBI) reports.  I use a "shared dataset" architecture.  That is, several reports will source from a single dataset.  This is achieved by a Live connection (with a dataset in the PBI Service as the source, as opposed to Azure Tabular as the source).  If it matters, for this particular situation, the PBI Service puts the dataset into Analysis Services.

My users need to export the underlying data from all visuals.  I have enabled this option on all "model" and "report" pbix files.  Also, I have enabled the Build permission on all reports (at the app level).  However, when a user selects Export data \ Underlying data, it returns just 1 row of the measures / aggregates.  It's not even slicing it by the dimensions as with Export data \ Summarized data (i.e., "Underlying data" is less granular than "Summarized data", which is backwards).  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable build permission on the dataset, not just the report.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: As far as I know, Build permission only applies to datasets, not reports (or other objects).  So, I should have said that I granted Build permission to all datasets, not reports.  Again, I granted this Build permission during app publishing.  To be sure, I don't have the exceptional scenario of the 'Entire organization' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: In Power BI Desktop, select

```
File > Options and Settings > Options > Current File > Report Settings
> Export Data subtitle > “Allow End Users to Export Both Summarized and 
Underlying Data from the Service.”
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  It didn't resolve my issue.